# get and set variable with argument

Tags: swift

I have a technical question in swift.
I want to have a variable that I can pass It a boolean argument and it saves this value in `UserDefaults` and when I call the variable it returns me the value that stores in `UserDefaults`.

Something like this:

```
var continuousPurchase: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "continuousPurchase")
    }
    set(value) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "continuousPurchase")
    }
}
```

I know that the "get" part is ok but I don't know how to write the "set" part

Should I write closure for setting the `UserDefaults` ?

Could someone help me please?

Edit:
I want to write this for setting UserDefaults:

```
continuousPurchase(true)
```

and write this for using the variable:

```
continuousPurchase
```

Comment: are you confused about how to use setter?

Comment: Your code compiles and looks correct at first sight – what exactly is your question?

Comment: @arash, when you do `continuousPurchase  = false`, your setter will be called and `value` will be false.

Comment: the question edited

Comment: @NikhilManapure yeah I got it Thanks, Is there anyway to write like in my question ?

Comment: Not without adding a `func continuousPurchase(_ value: Bool)` to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, you can remove the explicit `value` argument if you want, because setters have an implicit argument called `newValue` that you can use:

```
var continuousPurchase: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "continuousPurchase")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "continuousPurchase")
    }
}
```

and use `continuousPurchase = true` to set it.